# Segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

In C, when I try to run this program, I get a "Segmentation fault".  What does it mean? How can I fix this?

```
Tag tagNewDataPoint(const double x[MAX_DIMENSION],
                    const double w[MAX_DIMENSION],
                    const int d)
{
    int separator_arr,point_arr;
    double result = 0;
    for (separator_arr=0;separator_arr<d;separator_arr++)
    {
        for (point_arr=0;point_arr<d;separator_arr++)
        {
            result += w[separator_arr]*x[point_arr];
        }
    }

    if (result <0)
    {
        return NEG;
    }
    else if (result >0)
    {
        return POS;
    }
    else
    {
        return NOTAG;
    }
}
```

Comment: As a point of style, you might do better to name your index variables something like "point_ind" instead of "point_arr". Calling something "point_arr" gives the impression that it is an array, which of course it's not in this case.

Comment: @sinsedrix I tried to edit it , it showed write more lines , your question is filled with code.

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
for (point_arr=0;point_arr<d;separator_arr++)
```

should be:

```
for (point_arr=0;point_arr<d;point_arr++)
```

You increment the `separator_arr`, but checks the `pointer_arr` value (which is never changed) soon enough `separator_arr` is too big, and your address is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

You have index crosstalk.

`for (point_arr=0;point_arr<d;separator_arr++)`

should be

`for (point_arr=0;point_arr<d;point_arr++)`